# Let $0 \to \mathbb{Q} \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{Q}^{m} \to \mathbb{Q} \to 0$ be a exact sequence is $m=2$ always?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $0 \to \mathbb{Q} \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{Q}^{m} \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb{Q} \to 0$ be a exact sequence, since $f$ is injective it's clear that the image of $f$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

So it's true that if $A$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}^{m}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ then $\mathbb{Q}^{m} / A\cong \mathbb{Q}^{m-1}$ ?

Comment: Yes - any group homomorphism of $\mathbb Q^n\to\mathbb Q^m$ is also  a linear transformation of vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$, and you get lots of nice dimension properties with vector spaces and linear transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking dimensions you get $1-m+1=0$. If you have an exact sequence $$0\to V_n\to \cdots\to V_1\to 0$$ of finite dimensional vector spaces then $$\sum (-1)^i\dim V_i=0$$

Comment: The OP seems to be viewing $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q^m$ merely as groups (under addition). Do they automatically get a unique vector space structure? Otherwise it is not clear that speaking about dimensions is well defined.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well actually the question comes from the typical exercise : How many abelian groups (finitely generated) fit in this exact sequence? So I just localized the $\mathbb{Z}$-Modules by $\mathbb{Z}^{*}$ to compute the rank. So I think it's fine if I work with $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces

Comment: Yes - any group homomorphism $\mathbb Q^n\to\mathbb Q^m$ is a linear transformation - just take a basis of the domain, and show that $f(qe_i)=qf(e_i)$ for any $e_i$. This would not be true for $\mathbb R^{n}\to\mathbb R^m$. It is true for the prime fields $F=\mathbb Q,\mathbb F_p$, but not other fields. In the other fields, there are group homomorphism $F\to F$ which are not linear. @HenningMakholm